# Getting infinite columns

Tags: excel, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy and paste the image below into a different excel file.

[image]

When I create a new sheet, it looks like this, and the next pic is when I paste the original sheet.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: ... maybe don't use View, Workbook Views, Page Layout perhaps?

Comment: In what sense does this constitute "infinite columns"? I suspect that the columns still have slightly over a million rows hence are perfectly finite.